# How to convert a Python file to a PowerShell file?

Tags: python, powershell, type-conversion

So, I made a Python file (.py) and I want to convert it into a PowerShell file (.ps1)
I tried this tool: https://github.com/x-j/ps1scriptify but every time I give it a .py file, it says:
Python script provided is not callable (does not contain a main block)
So I changed this:  `print("Hello, World")` to this:
`def main():`
    `print("Hello, world")`
`main()`
It still gives me the same error mentioned above.
Any help please?

Comment: Why not call the python script from your PowerShell script, like `python my_module.py` would execute your script and you can even store it in a variable to access outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That conversion script is expecting to see a block like

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so pop that into your script instead of just the raw call to `main()`.